# How can I make a glowing or shiny gold material similar to these pictures?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, materials, node-editor

You would really help me.

Thank you in advance.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Part of this would come from the compositor, something like a glare node, and it appears to have a soft-grain effect over the whole frame.

Answer (score 2):

Here is setup that works for both Eevee and Cycles and seems not too far from what you show: Put a *Point* light into your object, and for your material use a mix between *Diffuse*, *Emission* and *Translucent* node, with an *Attibute* node as factor that uses the *Color Vertex Paint > Dirty Vertex Group* in order to keep some parts more opaque:

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Here's an easy material that should work for you
[image]

[image]